# TCL tablelist - how to use -editendcommand to read the modified values

Tags: tcl

Hi I'm new to tablelist and exploring the option to read the modified values after editing the cell.

```
global canvas  
set canvas .t  
tablelist::tablelist .t -columns { 0 TYPE  0 VALUE}  -selectmode single \
        -selecttype row -editselectedonly 0 -editstartcommand editStartCmd \
        -editendcommand editEndCmd
```

using the `editStartcomand` call function i was able to get the cell being edited

```
proc editStartCmd {canvas row column initialText} {  
    global cell  
    set cell $row,$column  
    return $initialText  
}
```

Now I am not able to know the procedure to get the modified value, to compare between the text before editing and after editing. I read the INTERACTIVE CELL EDITING under table list, but looking for an example to figure out the procedure exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have it in the tablelist creation command:

```
-editendcommand editEndCmd
```

You can define the proc `editEndCmd` to compare the values. Let's say you make the variable `$initialText` a global variable from the proc `editStartCmd`, then you can use something like:

```
proc editEndCmd {canvas row column finalText} {  
    global initialText

    # e.g. both initialText and finalText are numbers
    # Make the proc print 1 if the modified value is smaller, 0 if larger or equal 
    # to the initial value

    puts [expr {$initialText > $finalText}]

    return $finalText
}
```

If `$finalText` is not appropriate, you can make the above proc return `$initialText` so that it will revert the inserted value to its previous value.

Comment: its much clear!! and I'm moving forward. Appreciate the help!!